# Android Check network status on every single activity (continuously)

Tags: java, android

Right now I can check network status on a single activity and its really working fine. But suppose I want to check the internet on every single activity. How to modify this code? I tried many ways but failed.

```
package com.example.wohhi.nointernetsnackbar;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private TextView status;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "CheckNetworkStatus";
private NetworkChangeReceiver receiver;
private boolean isConnected = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    receiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

}

public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Receieved notification about network status");
        isNetworkAvailable(context);

    }


    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                if (info.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                    if(!isConnected){
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Now you are connected to Internet!");
                        String status = "Now you are connected to Internet!";
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.activity_main), status, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        isConnected = true;
                        //do your processing here ---
                        //if you need to post any data to the server or get status
                        //update from the server
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "You are not connected to Internet!");
        String status = "You are not connected to Internet!";
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.activity_main), status, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        isConnected = false;
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can't you use `BaseActivity` or common class?

Comment: I want to create a common class but the problem is I tried a lot but every time it produces new problem.

Comment: what problem it exactly produces?

Comment: It will show only one time the status after that it disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of registering it in onCreate() Create a BroadcastReceiver class outside of activity and register it statically means in Manifest. But this will work for only API level 23 and below as it is given [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION).

> Apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher do not receive this broadcast if they declare the broadcast receiver in their manifest. Apps will still receive broadcasts if they register their BroadcastReceiver with Context.registerReceiver() and that context is still valid.

Comment: with XML tag ''<receiver></receiver>"?

Comment: yes. In your case it should be like: `<receiver
            android:name="com.example.wohhi.nointernetsnackbar.NetworkChangeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>  `

Comment: android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE is depreciated. (Collecting for android warnings) - "Declaring a broadcastreceiver for android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE is deprecated for apps targeting N and higher. In general, apps should not rely on this broadcast and instead use JobScheduler or GCMNetworkManager"

Comment: Then one more way is there, create  a class which will extend Application class. And then in onCreate method of Application you can register your receiver and in onDestroy method of Application you can unregister it. In this way, broadcast receiver will be available throughout application cycle instead of activity cycle.

Comment: If this is not working then you need to go with JobScheduler only.